# jQuery attribute selector does not work

Tags: jquery

I have the following element in my html:

```
<button id="btn-confirm-cancel-22" type="button" class="font-size-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelProposalConfirationModal" data-cancel-rid="22">Cancel</button>
```

And this jQuery function:

```
$("[data-cancel-rid]").on('click', function (event) {
    var request_id = $(this).attr('data-cancel-rid');
    console.log(request_id);
});
```

When clicking the button the browser does not call the jQuery function. Why???

Comment: Is this function wrapped in `jQuery(document).ready(function() {});`?

Comment: yes. It is wrapped in jQuery(document)... Actually there is very similar function there which works just fine. There's got to be a little something that I just missed.

Comment: It works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/pqrofcck/

Comment: Is the `data-cancel-rid` attribute hard coded in the HTML or appended with `jQuery.data()` function?

Comment: data-cancel-rid is hard coded in the html.

Comment: It seems the problem is on console.log. I've used alert instead of console.log instead, and function returned 22. http://jsfiddle.net/u3m5geuL

Comment: @MohammadSaberi I click the button in fiddle and it doesn't work. what am I missing?

Comment: Why don't you use the id for to select the button?

Comment: @mo.dhouibi I have many such buttons (the button's id contains running number) so I need to have this click function to apply on all of them.

Comment: @dsb your code, copy/paste, worked 100% fine for me, So I think you should looks somewhere else for the error. I am using  jQuery v1.11.1    .cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either wrap the whole function inside, also could be because of non-delegation:

```
$(function () {
  $("body").on('click', "[data-cancel-rid]", function (event) {
    var request_id = $(this).attr('data-cancel-rid');
    console.log(request_id);
  });
});
```

Or load the code in the end of the document, before `</body>` tag. When the code executes, may be the `document` is not loaded.

Comment: It is wrapped in $(document).ready(function () {..}); and also there are other functions in this file which work just fine (actually I copy-pasted one of them).

Comment: @dsb Try delegating the function. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes. I just figured out that people here were right. This button is being created after the page was loaded (the button created via ajax call). I expected the jQuery to perform on the new button but apparently it didn't. This did the trick. Thank you.